# Find and replace expresion with quotes with sed

Tags: sed, pattern-matching

I want to **replace a line** of python code, which **contain quotes**

The line in the original file looks like this:

```
ScalarLogger("results.dat" ,('t',) + exp_data)
```

And I want to **replace it to**

```
ScalarLogger("results_j" + str(sys.argv[1]) + "_h" + str(sys.argv[2]) + ".dat" , ('t',) + exp_data)
```

Therefore, my approach was to use the `sed` command:

```
sed -i 'e/results.dat/results_j" + str(sys.argv[1]) + "_h" + str(sys.argv[2]) + ".dat/g' run.py
```

However, I'm getting the following **error**:

```
sh: 1: /results.dat/results_j + str(sys.argv[1]) + _h + str(sys.argv[2]) + .dat/g: not found
```

I tried changing the `/` character, but still does not work.

Comment: `e/` should be `s/`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can you write it as an answer please. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sed` expression seems to say `e/.../.../g` rather than `s/.../.../g`.

[The `e` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Extended-Commands.html) is a GNU extension to the standard `sed` utility which uses the argument (your pattern, including the `/` characters and the final `/g`) as a shell command, replacing the data with the output of that command (a bit like a command substitution).

Luckily for you, the command was not found rather than being a valid, destructive, shell command.

Answer (score 0):

command

```
awk -F "." '{print $1"_j""\""" + str(sys.argv[1]) + ""\"""_h""\""" + str(sys.argv[2]) +""\"""."$2}' filename
 
 sed -e 's/results/&_j" + str(sys.argv[1]) + "_h" + str(sys.argv[2]) + /g' -e 's/\.dat/"&/g' filename
```

python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
m=open('filename','r')
for i in m:
    k=i.split(".")
    print k[0]+'_j" + str(sys.argv[1])+'+'"_h" + str(sys.argv[2]) + ".'+k[1]
```

output

```
ScalarLogger("results_j" + str(sys.argv[1]) + "_h" + str(sys.argv[2]) +".dat" ,('t',) + exp_data)
```